# How Do I Solve: [ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:]

Tags: valueerror, python-3.9

```py
    command= " "
    while True:
        command = int(input("how old are you? "))
        if command <= 12:
            print("you're ticket is free.")
        elif command <= 15:
            print("you're ticket is $20.")
        elif command > 15:
            print("you're ticket is $50.")
        elif command == "exit":
            break
```

As I write `exit` it gives a `ValueError`,

```py
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:'exit'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check if the command is exit before trying to convert the command to int:

```py
while True:
    command = input("how old are you? ")
    if command == "exit":
        break
    command = int(command)
    if command <= 12:
        print("you're ticket is free.")
    elif command <= 15:
        print("you're ticket is $20.")
    elif command > 15:
        print("you're ticket is $50.")
```